# extjs formpanel not display pdf from response

Tags: gwt, extjs

I am using "com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FormPanel" and have problem to display pdf at client. I have submitted request, where html is converted to pdf and put in OutputStream, so that it will populate pdf at client.  I am able to see the pdf using sencha/gwt FormPanel but same code is not working with extjs component.

Code:

```
 FormPanel form = new FormPanel();
 form.setEncoding(FormPanel.Encoding.URLENCODED);
 form.setMethod(FormPanel.Method.POST);
 form.getElement().setAttribute("target", "_blank");
 form.setAction(url);
 form.submit();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Extjs FormPanel uses ajax to do Submits (I've verified in Extjs 3.X and 4.X).  You may get it to work with:

```
form.getEl().dom.submit()
```

Because that would do the regular HTML form submit instead.

Comment: Hi Reimius, thanks, I try to use form.getElement().submit() but form.getElement() don't have submit() method. I am using com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.form.FormPanel and form.getElement() won't hava submit()

Comment: oh sorry, updated, what you need is to access the actual dom that is the form element, then use it's submit

Comment: No form.getEl().dom.submit() don't have form.getElement().dom (form.getEl() not found so I thought it's getElement())

Comment: What version of Extjs are you using, do you know?